# Spivak's Calculus, Ch. 13 "Integrals", Problem *21b: Prove $\int_a^b f^{-1}=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)-\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)}f$.

Tags: calculus, integration

The following is a problem from Ch. 13 "Integrals" from Spivak's Calculus

> *21. Suppose that $f$ is increasing. Figure 16 suggests that
>
> $$\int_a^b
>  f^{-1}=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)-\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)}f\tag{1}$$
>
> (a) If $P=\{t_0,...,t_1\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, let
> $P'=\{f^{-1}(t_0),...,f^{-1}(t_n)\}$. Prove that, as suggested in
> Figure 17,
>
> $$L(f^{-1},P)+U(f,P')=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)\tag{2}$$
>
> (b) Now prove the formula stated above (ie, $(1)$).

Here are the cited figures

[image]

[image]

Proving $(a)$ is straightforward. We just write out what $L(f^{-1},P)$ and $U(f,P')$ are

$$L(f^{-1},P)=\sum f^{-1}(t_{i-1})\cdot (t_i-t_{i-1})$$

$$U(f,P')=\sum t_i(f^{-1}(t_i)-f^{-1}(t_{i-1}))$$

and add them to reach $(2)$ after some algebra.

My question is about $(b)$.

Here is the solution from the solution manual.

> $$\int_a^bf^{-1}=\sup{L(f^{-1},P)}=\sup \left
>  ({bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)-U(f,P')}\right )\tag{3}$$
>
> $$=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)-\inf{U(f,P')}\tag{4}$$
>
> $$=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)-\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(n)}f$$

Why can we go from $(3)$ to $(4)$? Specifically it seems the solution goes from $\sup U(f,P')$ to $\inf U(f,P')$.

Comment: $\sup \{c-a: a \in A\}=c-\inf \{a: a \in A\}$:  a basic fact about sup and inf of sets in $\mathbb R$.